# Dynamic Multiple json Array in Android Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit

In the json below i am able to read the fields in "**categories**" using the following android code. I hava no idea how to read the **"effect_list"** elements **"4"** and **"1"** . The "4" and "1" are incremental and **Dynamic**. How should i create a pojo class for this and how my code should be in **Main_get.java** ?

```
             {  
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "mcategory_id":"4",
         "mcategory_name":"Band"

      },
      {  
         "mcategory_id":"1",
         "mcategory_name":"Basic Effects"

      },
      {  
         "mcategory_id":"3",
         "mcategory_name":"Bg Image Card"

      }

   ],
   "effect_list":{  
      "4":[  
         {  
            "effects_id":"18",
            "effects_name":"Band 1"

         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"19",
            "effects_name":"Band 2"

         }

      ],
      "1":[  
         {  
            "effects_id":"1",
            "effects_name":"Background Blur"

         },
         {  
            "effects_id":"4",
            "effects_name":"Blemish Removal"

         }
        ] 
   }  
}
```

I am using the following code to get json Array **"categories"** using retrofit and its working without any problem. Now how can i get the **"effect_list"** fields?

**Contact.java**

```
   public class Contact {


    @SerializedName("mcategory_id")
    @Expose
    private String mcategory_id;


    @SerializedName("mcategory_name")
    @Expose
    private String mcategory_name;


   public String getmcategory_id() {
       return name;
    }


    public void setmcategory_id(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getmcategory_name() {
        return email;
    }


    public void setmcategory_name(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

**ApiService.java**

```
     public interface ApiService {

    @GET("xyz.json")
    Call<ContactList> getMyJSON();
   }
```

**ContactList.java**

```
         public class ContactList {

        @SerializedName("contacts")
        @Expose
        public ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

/**
 * @return The contacts
 */
      public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
      return contacts;
    }

/**
 * @param contacts The contacts
 */
    public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }
}
```

**RetroClient.java**

```
       public class RetroClient {


    private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://abc.ab/";


    private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    }

    /**
     * Get API Service
     *
     * @return API Service
     */
    public static ApiService getApiService() {
        return getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiService.class);
    }
}
```

**MyContactAdapter.java**

```
          List<Contact> contactList;
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    // Constructors
    public MyContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        contactList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
            View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.get_layout_row_view,              parent, false);
        vh = ViewHolder.create((RelativeLayout) view);
        view.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Contact item = getItem(position);


    vh.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
    vh.textViewEmail.setText(item.getEmail());
    //  Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePic()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
    Picasso.with(context).load(item.getProfilePic()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);

    //   loading.dismiss();

    return vh.rootView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public final RelativeLayout rootView;
    public final ImageView imageView;
    public final TextView textViewName;
    public final TextView textViewEmail;

    public ViewHolder(RelativeLayout rootView, ImageView imageView, TextView textViewName, TextView textViewEmail) {
        this.rootView = rootView;
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.textViewName = textViewName;
        this.textViewEmail = textViewEmail;
    }

    public static ViewHolder create(RelativeLayout rootView) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        TextView textViewEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        return new ViewHolder(rootView, imageView, textViewName, textViewEmail);
    }
}
```

**Main_get.java**

```
           public class  Main_get extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Views
     */
    private GridView listView;
    private View parentView;

    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
    private MyContactAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    /**
     * Array List for Binding Data from JSON to this List
     */
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    parentView = findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

    /**
     * Getting List and Setting List Adapter
     */
    listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {
            Snackbar.make(parentView, contactList.get(position).getName() +   " => " + contactList.get(position).getName().getBytes(),   Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    assert fab != null;
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(@NonNull final View view) {





            //Creating an object of our api interface
            ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();

            /**
             * Calling JSON
             */
            Call<ContactList> call = api.getMyJSON();

            /**
             * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
             */
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactList>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call,     Response<ContactList> response) {


                    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                        /**
                         * Got Successfully
                         */
                        contactList = response.body().getContacts();

                        /**
                         * Binding that List to Adapter
                         */
                        adapter = new MyContactAdapter( Main_get.this, contactList);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } else {
                        //  Snackbar.make(parentView,     R.string.string_some_thing_wrong, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ContactList> call, Throwable t) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

        } 


      });
  }
 }
```

What are all the changes i should do in this code?

Comment: You should not have Dynamic JsonObjects inside a JsonObject like in your Json. You should use Dynamic JsonObjects inside a JsonArray.

Comment: I think you should fix the json into something more parsable. You can put the effect as part of the the contact object

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Map<Integer, List<Effect>>
```

In Integer you'll get index ("1", "4"...) and in List you'll get array of effects.

Comment: thanks for the answer, what are the changes i should make in **Main_get.java**?